# WxPython attribute error, *my class* object has no attribute *my function*

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Python 2.7

Ubuntu 12.04

My code is available [here](http://pastebin.com/h1Pyk8y6).

I'm trying to put together a base for myself to make creating wxPython apps easier, I'm using the set up of my last program as that base but it's not working properly.

The problem arises when I try to bind a button to a function, this is the same layout that has worked for me before but now when I try to start the program with the button and the bind in place I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'my_panel' object has no attribute 'on_quit'
```

If I remove the bind the program launches.

What's going on?

I've looked at other questions regarding this and it seems that most of the time it's a typing error, I've looked but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on_quit method in your code is indented too far. It needs to be at the same indention level as the init function. This is what you have:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    """docstring for __"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.frame = parent

    self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.widget_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    self.text_object = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Example')
    self.button_object = wx.Button(self, -1, 'QUIT')
    self.button_object.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_quit)

    self.widget_sizer.Add(self.text_object, 0)
    self.widget_sizer.Add(self.button_object, 0)

    self.main_sizer.Add(self.widget_sizer, 0)


    def on_quit(self, event):
        """docstring for on"""
        self.Close()
```

This is what it should look like:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    """docstring for __"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.frame = parent

    self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.widget_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    self.text_object = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Example')
    self.button_object = wx.Button(self, -1, 'QUIT')
    self.button_object.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_quit)

    self.widget_sizer.Add(self.text_object, 0)
    self.widget_sizer.Add(self.button_object, 0)

    self.main_sizer.Add(self.widget_sizer, 0)


def on_quit(self, event):
    """docstring for on"""
    self.Close()
```

Also note that "self.Close()" will not work. It should be **self.frame.Close()**

Comment: That did it, not sure why I totally missed that.